# Python: In an xml, How to delete nodes within a parent node

Tags: python, xml

I have a pretty big xml, from which I need to **delete some specific nodes within another node**.
e.g. I have a list which contains the name of nodes which should be present in the xml. So, apart from these nodes all other nodes within the parent node should be deleted and to be written into a new xml file.

I need to delete only the nodes i.e. '**Instance**' in which the first '**Data**' element is not equal to a value present in my list which I'll provide. Rest of the xml info i.e. '**Description**', '**Symbols**' tag should not be disturbed.

Assumptions:I have parsed the data which should be read from the external file into a python list variable.

DOM or SAX anyone is ok for me. But I believe DOM is very quick.
Any hints to any BIF's available or logic will also be fine for me.

Note:I'm new to Python. So please comment if any thing wrong in my code.

My code below:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse('Test.xml')

file = open("File.txt")

list = []

for lines in file:
    list.append(lines)

Instance = tree.findall('Instance')
for i in Instance:
   while (i != list[i]):
       Instance.remove(i)

tree.write('new.xml')
```

Below is the sample xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Identification>
<Description ID="12">Some text</Description>
</Identification>
<Symbols>
  <Name Width="1">abc</Name>
  <Name Width="2">def</Name>
</Symbols>

<Instance RowRef="A">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>12345678</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
</Instance>
<Instance RowRef="B">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>87654321</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
</Instance>
<Instance RowRef="C">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>06354237/Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
```

Comment: @Vivek: I have updated the question details with my code.With my code all xml tag's are getting replaced with "ns0:". I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What's the content of `File.txt`?

Comment: @Yoel:'File.txt' will contain some 'Data' values e.g. '12345678','87654321'. Justin has guessed it correct in his answer.Please refer the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused on a number of points.

**First**, the xml you provide lacks a root tag. Your xml file should look something more like this (where `Root` can be replaced with whatever tag is necessary):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Root>
<Identification>
<Description ID="12">Some text</Description>
</Identification>
<Symbols>
  <Name Width="1">abc</Name>
  <Name Width="2">def</Name>
</Symbols>

<Instance RowRef="A">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>12345678</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
</Instance>
<Instance RowRef="B">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>87654321</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
</Instance>
<Instance RowRef="C">
  <DataSet>
    <Data>06354237</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
  </DataSet>
</Instance>
</Root>
```

**Second**, if you are concerned about speed, consider using `cElementTree` instead of `ElementTree`:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET  # use cElementTree for faster processing
```

**Third**, you need to assign a name to the result of the `ET.parse` method, or you will have no way to reference it later:

```
>>> tree = ET.parse('Test.xml')
```

**Fourth**, now you need to find the root of that tree before you find all the `Instance` elements of that tree:

```
>>> root = tree.getroot()  # now get the root
>>> keeper_data = ['06354237', '87654321']  # your list that you will apparently get from a file?
>>> instances = root.findall('Instance')
```

Now you need to find `Instance` elements whose `Data` values indicate that the `Instance` element should be deleted:

**Fifth**, you need to check whether the text of the first `Data` element is in your keeper list, and **sixth**, you `remove` your element from the `root` (or whatever the parent happens to be) and NOT from `instances`:

```
>>> for instance in instances:
        data1 = instance.find('./DataSet/Data')
        if data1.text not in keeper_data:
            # NOTE WELL: I remove from the root (not the instance) below!
            root.remove(instance)
```

Now write to your new xml file:

```
>>> tree.write('New.xml')
```

Your resulting xml file will look like this:

```
<Root>
 <Identification>
  <Description ID="12">Some text</Description>
 </Identification>
 <Symbols>
  <Name Width="1">abc</Name>
  <Name Width="2">def</Name>
 </Symbols>
 <Instance RowRef="B">
  <DataSet>
   <Data>87654321</Data>
  </DataSet>
   <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
   </DataSet>
   <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
   </DataSet>
  </Instance>
  <Instance RowRef="C">
   <DataSet>
    <Data>06354237</Data>
   </DataSet>
   <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
   </DataSet>
   <DataSet>
    <Data>abcd</Data>
   </DataSet>
  </Instance>
 </Root>
```

Note that the Instance with a Data element with value 12345678 and none of the the other keeper_data elements has been omitted.

Comment: Yes, you were correct, I haven't mentioned in my question which 'Data' values to compare with. But you have guessed it right, it was the first 'Data' element only. But this code of yours also gave me error like this: "ValueError:list.remove(x): x not in list". This error went off when I added one more break after the 'remove' statement and then new xml is printing fine as expected.But still the original xml of mine is giving the ValueError.Any idea what might be the cause ?

Comment: @manty Be sure that your `else` statement falls directly under the `for` statement and *not* under the `if` statement. The `else` statement should only run after all the `Data` elements have been run through. It belongs to the `for` loop. If you line up its indentation with the `if` statement, you might try to remove an `Instance` element twice and will get the error you mention.

Comment: @manty Note that I have also modified the code slightly, since you indicated in your comment above that you would like only to check the value of the first `Data` element against your `keeper_list`. If my answer has helped you resolve your issue, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) as the correct answer.

Comment: Though my original xml is not working as expected(which I think is more of my issue), but what I was looking for is perfectly solved by your answer.Hence, I have accepted your answer as the correct one. Thanks Justin

Comment: Just posted the relevant question of my issue. Please check once. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084901/python-why-this-error-is-coming)