# Python: Why this error is coming?

Tags: python, xml

With reference to this question:            [Python: In an xml, How to delete nodes within a parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078225/python-in-an-xml-how-to-delete-nodes-within-a-parent-node)

Can anyone explain me why I'm facing this issue in my python script.

```
Value Error : list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Code below.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

try:
   tree = ET.parse('Test.xml')
   root = tree.getroot()
   keeper_data = ['06354237', '87654321']
   instances = root.findall('./Replication/Instance')
   for instance in instances:
       data = instance.find('./DataSet/Data')
       if data.text not in keeper_data:
          root.remove(instance)

tree.write('New.xml')

except ValueError as err:
     print ('Value Error : ' + str(err))
```

xml sample below.Please note the only difference in xml structure from previous question is the addition of "Replication" tag which encloses all the  tags.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Root>
<Identification>
   <Description ID="12">Some text</Description>
</Identification>
<Symbols>
  <Name Width="1">abc</Name>
  <Name Width="2">def</Name>
</Symbols>
<Replication  iRowRef="884">
   <Instance RowRef="A">
      <DataSet>
          <Data>12345678</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
          <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
          <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
   </Instance>
   <Instance RowRef="B">
      <DataSet>
         <Data>87654321</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
         <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
         <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
   </Instance>
   <Instance RowRef="C">
      <DataSet>
         <Data>06354237</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
         <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
      <DataSet>
         <Data>abcd</Data>
      </DataSet>
  </Instance>
</Replication>
</Root>
```

Comment: The error doesn’t match your code. Also don’t just put everything inside a `try` block. That way you lose important error information. Remove that block and only place it where you *explicitely* want to catch a certain error.

Comment: @poke Can you please explain how the error is not matching with my code? That's actually the output error I'm getting from my program.

Comment: @poke, that's actually the exact error message. It includes the type, not the variable name, and `x` as a placeholder for the item. Try `foo = []; foo.remove("bar")` and Python (3.3.5) will say `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

Comment: @poke, I can reproduce the error message if I run OP's code. (I should append a missing `</Root>` to the XML file)

Comment: That's some thing python is complaining about the object 'instance' which I have passed in 'root.remove(instance)'. 'x' refers to 'instance' and 'root' is the 'list'.

Comment: @manty, `root` is not a list, but a `Element` instance.

Comment: @falsetru Thanks for pointing out.Added the missing </Root> tag in question.

Comment: @manty, You'd better to include full traceback. Try your program without `try ... except ...`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Interesting. Well, that’s why I suggested to remove the `try` block…

Comment: @falsetru The program works without the `try..except..` block also, but don't you think it's a good practice to use them always, while dealing with files.

Comment: @manty, You just printed an error message in the `except` block, which is less information than full traceback. If you don't do the special treatment for the exception, it would be better without `try ... except ...`.

Comment: @falsetru Well, that's something I'm confused about.I'm just into learning Python and I'm referring 'Head First Python' and this book enforces this type of code usage which I used above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use direct **parent** node, instead of the root node to use [`Element.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove).

I used [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) here, because ElementTree does not provide a method to get a parent node.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
keeper_data = ['06354237', '87654321']
instances = root.findall('./Replication/Instance')
for instance in instances:
    data = instance.find('./DataSet/Data')
    if data.text not in keeper_data:
        instance.getparent().remove(instance)
...
```